# How to say "it was nice meeting you yesterday"

Tags: translation, grammar, simplified-characters

I'm a newbie to Chinese. I'm learning it by myself. So I have some questions. Could you correct me if I'm wrong?

I want to say "It was nice meeting you yesterday" or "I was glad meeting you" etc.

1. I traslated it as 我昨天很高兴见到了你。Is it correct?  Can I say 我(昨天)很高兴见到了?
2. Do I need to use 了  here? Or 我昨天很高兴见到 and 我昨天很高兴见到 would also be correct?

Comment: It should be: 我很高兴昨天见到了你。

Comment: @fefe, I think both "我很高兴昨天见到了你" and "我昨天很高兴见到了你" can work. Also, 昨天，我很高兴见到了你。or 很高兴我昨天见到了你. All these sentences are correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way to go! You have made a perfect first Chinese sentence "我昨天很高兴见到了你。"!

In 我昨天很高兴见到, you might have to put a target for the verb '见到', so it would be like “我昨天很高兴见到你。”, which has the same meaning as "我昨天很高兴见到了你。"

‘了’ in this case can be omitted.

Comment: Welcome on-board! :)